# Use USB printer over TCP/IP

Tags: printing, tcp, ip, usb, zpl

I have an application that sends ZPL print jobs via TCP/IP to a client in the network (I can configure IP and Port). I have only a USB printer available that is attached to a client. How can I send print job to the client with the USB printer, and let this client print the job with the USB printer?

Sending to the client is not the problem, I just configure the IP and some Port. But how can the client print this via the USB printer?

Comment: You'll need to find out which protocol the application uses (LPR, RAW, ...) and then set up a print server for it.

Comment: It uses ZPL, what print server software can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of methods to do this.  They all require a app on the system that the USB printer is attached to.  You can send the ZPL to a generic raw driver. You can also use an SDK to send the ZPL to the USB printer.  If it's a Zebra printer, we have a Java and a .NET based SDK that can do this.  For a complete answer, it would be really helpful if you mentioned the platform/OS the printers will be connected to and the language the 'client' app will be written in.

Comment: It's a Zebra ZP450, the OS of the computer where it is attached is Windows 10, and I was hoping for a solution without writing a client app. Or is there any print server that supports Zebra ZP450 I could use?

Comment: If the print is being initiated by a client webpage, there are two options that would allow you to use Javascript to print.  One is to use the standard USB driver and the standard print functions in browsers.  It is problematic because the drivers have to be set up correctly and the website has to show the full label you want to print.  The other option is to use a tool called Browser Print to print ZPL.